# Asp.net 4 class object properties being set to null on return to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

ASP.NET 4.5 MVC using Razor

Hello, I am a Jr. dev and I've run into a problem where everything looks like it should work but I seem to be missing something. I am trying to pass a class object from a controller to a view that is used to update the database record for that object. My model, controller and view are as follows:

Model:

```
public class  Contract
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PartName { get; set; }
    public decimal PartPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet] //the code that genereates these parameters is next on the chopping block
    public ActionResult UpdateContractPricing(string customerNumber, string partNumber, decimal contractPrice, DateTime contractStart, DateTime contractEnd, string notes, int ID)

    {
        Contract currentContract = new Contract
        {
            ID = int.Parse(ID),
            PartName = partNumber,
            PartPrice = Decimal.Parse(contractPrice),
            StartDate = contractStart,
            EndDate = contractEnd,
            CustomerNumber = customerNumber,
            Notes = notes
        };
        ViewBag.currentContract = currentContract;

        return View(new Contract());
    }
```

View (`<p>` tags are for confirmation):

```
@using NewWebApplication.Models
@model NewWebApplication.Models.Contract

@{ 
Contract con = new Contract();
con = (Contract)ViewBag.currentContract;
var tes = "";//for use as a breakpoint only}

<p>@con.ID</p>
<p>@con.CustomerNumber</p>
<p>@con.PartName</p>
<p>@con.PartPrice</p>
<p>@con.StartDate</p>
<p>@con.EndDate</p>
<p>@con.Notes</p>
```

What currently happens is the currentContract object is successfully constructed with the correct info, but as soon as it's sent off to the view everything apparently gets set to null and I'm kicked to a System.ArgumentNullException. I have tried passing the object to the ViewBag and ViewData but get the same error.

VS 2015 spits out :

> -An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>   -Additional information: Value cannot be null.

And Chrome spits out:

> -Value cannot be null.
>   -Parameter name: String
>   -Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> -Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>     Parameter name: String

What's confusing me is the `currentContract` Object has all of its properties successfully set to a non-null value by the controller before being passed to the view. Have I missed something? Am I making a rookie mistake somewhere? Why is the view acting like I'm sending it a object full of nulls?

For the record, I have followed each of these tutorials to a T to no avail:

[First tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-Asp-Net-mvc/)

[Second tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-passing-data-from-controller-to-view/)

[Third tutorial](https://chsakell.com/2013/05/02/4-basic-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc/)

EDIT 8/2: I have corrected the typing in the model and controller. I have also tried creating a new Contract within the view called con. con has all of its properties copied from the viewbag data, **which is all correct and contains no nulls and is always successfully copied to con**. I am still getting the same ArgumentNullException on the first @con.property property I try to render, regardless of which one I try or what its value is.

Comment: It's probably exception on your `int.Parse()` in controller action, likely you have `null` passed there. MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Int32_Parse_System_String_

Comment: You could set a debug-breakpoint and verify your controller code.

Comment: @Samich , I've tried setting everything to string just in case that was it. Still throwing the same error.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I''ve been doing that. I'm able to see the object get made with all the correct information. It gets to "return View(currentContract);" and then then throws an error over the first p tag it tries to render.

Comment: Why are your parameters `string` when you want `int`, `decimal` and `DateTime`? That error will be generated if either `ID` or `contractPrice` is `null`

Comment: @Stephan I've properly typed the inputs, but I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that the ID or PartPrice values are null. you can try this:

```
Contract currentContract = new Contract
    {
        ID = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ID) ? 0 : int.Parse(ID),
        PartName = partNumber,
        PartPrice = string.IsNullOrEmpty(contractPrice) ? 0 : 
        Decimal.Parse(contractPrice),
        StartDate = contractStart,
        EndDate = contractEnd,
        CustomerNumber = customerNumber,
        Notes = notes
    };
```

Comment: They are not null, here's an example of what currentContract ends up as before being returned:      ID = "11436"
CustomerNumber = "001810"
PartName = "6203-ZZ "
StartDate = "REDACTED DATETIME"
EndDate = "REDACTED DATETIME"
Notes = "REDACTED"
PartPrice = REDACTED DECIMAL

Comment: how do you send the data to UpdateContractPricing? do you have another view  before  UpdateContractPricing?

Comment: I'm using a Url.Action to pass each parameter of a specific db entry to UpdateContractPricing from a table of entries with a button. I have had no issue with this.

Comment: I Copy and paste your code, I get the error when the PartPrice value is null, in your previous comment with you example data, you dont send value to "contractPrice",please, check if you are sending this value.

Comment: all values are being sent, every time. All of the input parameters correspond to non-nullable database fields and are being transferred properly, there should be  no case where nulls are coming from the controller. I am able to see this when I break at "return View(currentContract);", currentContract NEVER has a null in any field.